# syslog : How can I filter syslog messages on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, syslog

I would like to how I can filter syslog messages to get only the ones I am interested in on Windows 10.

For example I would like to get the syslog message when the identification/authentication of a user fails or succeed.

I found that for Linux I have to modify I have to modify the file /etc/rsyslog.conf but I am still confused on how to do it on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### how I can filter syslog messages to get only the ones I am interested in on Windows 10?

Windows does not use `syslog` to save information about system events such as identification/authentication of users.

It does, however, have a System Event Log which can be viewed using the [Windows Event Viewer](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/).

See [Filter by Event Identifier](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687416.aspx) for instructions of how to filter by specific events.

To trace identification/authentication of users you need to look for the following events:

> ```
> Windows   4624    An account was successfully logged on
> Windows   4625    An account failed to log on
> Windows   4626    User/Device claims information
> Windows   4627    Group membership information.
> Windows   4634    An account was logged off
> Windows   4646    IKE DoS-prevention mode started
> Windows   4647    User initiated logoff
> Windows   4648    A logon was attempted using explicit credentials
> Windows   4649    A replay attack was detected
> Windows   4650    An IPsec Main Mode security association was established
> Windows   4651    An IPsec Main Mode security association was established
> Windows   4652    An IPsec Main Mode negotiation failed
> Windows   4653    An IPsec Main Mode negotiation failed
> Windows   4654    An IPsec Quick Mode negotiation failed
> Windows   4655    An IPsec Main Mode security association ended
> Windows   4672    Special privileges assigned to new logon
> Windows   4675    SIDs were filtered
> Windows   4778    A session was reconnected to a Window Station
> Windows   4779    A session was disconnected from a Window Station
> Windows   4800    The workstation was locked
> Windows   4801    The workstation was unlocked
> Windows   4802    The screen saver was invoked
> Windows   4803    The screen saver was dismissed
> Windows   4964    Special groups have been assigned to a new logon
> Windows   4976    During Main Mode negotiation, IPsec received an invalid negotiation packet.
> Windows   4977    During Quick Mode negotiation, IPsec received an invalid negotiation packet.
> Windows   4978    During Extended Mode negotiation, IPsec received an invalid negotiation packet.
> Windows   4979    IPsec Main Mode and Extended Mode security associations were established.
> Windows   4980    IPsec Main Mode and Extended Mode security associations were established
> Windows   4981    IPsec Main Mode and Extended Mode security associations were established
> Windows   4982    IPsec Main Mode and Extended Mode security associations were established
> Windows   4983    An IPsec Extended Mode negotiation failed
> Windows   4984    An IPsec Extended Mode negotiation failed
> Windows   5378    The requested credentials delegation was disallowed by policy
> Windows   5451    An IPsec Quick Mode security association was established
> Windows   5452    An IPsec Quick Mode security association ended
> Windows   5453    An IPsec negotiation with a remote computer failed because the IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules (IKEEXT) service is not started
> Windows   5632    A request was made to authenticate to a wireless network
> Windows   5633    A request was made to authenticate to a wired network
> Windows   6272    Network Policy Server granted access to a user
> Windows   6273    Network Policy Server denied access to a user
> Windows   6274    Network Policy Server discarded the request for a user
> Windows   6275    Network Policy Server discarded the accounting request for a user
> Windows   6276    Network Policy Server quarantined a user
> Windows   6277    Network Policy Server granted access to a user but put it on probation because the host did not meet the defined health policy
> Windows   6278    Network Policy Server granted full access to a user because the host met the defined health policy
> Windows   6279    Network Policy Server locked the user account due to repeated failed authentication attempts
> Windows   6280    Network Policy Server unlocked the user account
> ```

Source [Windows Security Log Encyclopedia](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/) filtered by  "Logon/Logoff" and "Win2008, Win2012R2, Win2016 and Win10+"

---

Further Reading

- [What information appears in the event logs? Any errors? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)
- [Logon/Logoff Events](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter5)